# How to update a data of a node in d3 force layout using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

i am trying to creata a d3 force layout graph using react i am refering to this https://codepen.io/vialito/pen/RympKp example when i tried to update a data of the node the data is not reflecting in the data associated with the links and nodes gets disconnected from the links can anyone please help me out here is my following code.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      addLinkArray: [],
      name: "",
      nodes:
        [
          {"name": "fruit", "id": 0},
          {"name": "apple", "id": 1},
          {"name": "orange", "id": 2},
          {"name": "banana", "id": 3}
        ],
      links:
        [
          {"source": 0, "target": 1, "id": 0},
          {"source": 0, "target": 2, "id": 1}
        ]
      }
    this.handleAddNode = this.handleAddNode.bind(this)
    this.addNode = this.addNode.bind(this)
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this)
    this.updateFlag = "";
  }

    componentDidMount() {

        const data = this.state;
            FORCE.initForce(data.nodes, data.links)
                FORCE.tick(this)
                FORCE.drag()
        console.log("after mount",this.state.links);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if ((prevState.nodes !== this.state.nodes || prevState.links !== this.state.links)) {
            const data = this.state;
                console.log("comp update");
                console.log(this.state.nodes);
                console.log(this.state.links);

                FORCE.initForce(this.state.nodes,this.state.links);
                FORCE.tick(this);
                FORCE.drag();
                this.updateFlag = "";
        }

    }
    componentWillMount() {
      console.log("before mount",this.state.links);
    }

  handleAddNode(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

  addNode(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            nodes: [...prevState.nodes, { name:this.state.name, id: prevState.nodes.length + 1, }], name: ''
        }));
        this.updateFlag = "created";
    }
    handleDelete() {
      this.setState(prevState=>({
        links:prevState.links.filter((node,i)=>{
          return i != 0
        }),
        nodes:prevState.nodes.filter((node,i)=>{
          return i != 1
        })
      }))
      this.updateFlag = "deleted";
    }
    handleUpdate() {
      const state2 = update(this.state.nodes, {0: {name: {$apply: function(x){ return "fruit2"}}}});

      this.setState({
        nodes : state2
      })
      console.log("this",this.state.links);
      //FORCE.initForce(this.state.nodes,this.state.links);

    }

    render() {
        var links = this.state.links.map( (link) => {
            return (
                <Link
                    key={link.id}
                    data={link}
                />);
        });
        var nodes = this.state.nodes.map( (node) => {
              return (
              <Node
                  data={node}
                  name={node.name}
                  key={node.id}
              />);
          });
        return (
          <div className="graph__container">
            <form className="form-addSystem" onSubmit={this.addNode.bind(this)}>
              <h4 className="form-addSystem__header">New Node</h4>
              <div className="form-addSystem__group">
                <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleAddNode.bind(this)}
                  name="name"
                  className="form-addSystem__input"
                  id="name"
                  placeholder="Name"/>
                <label className="form-addSystem__label" htmlFor="title">Name</label>
              </div>
              <div className="form-addSystem__group">
                <input className="btnn" type="submit" value="add node" />
                <input className="btnn" onClick = {this.handleDelete} type="button" value="delete" />
                <input className="btnn" onClick = {this.handleUpdate} type="button" value="update" />
              </div>
            </form>
            <svg className="graph" width={FORCE.width} height={FORCE.height}>
                <g>
                    {links}
                </g>
                <g>
                    {nodes}
                </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see any detail on the update function, but I suspect it's returning the same array object. So, when you do the comparison in componentDidUpdate, it wouldn't fire.

Here's a change to try  -

```
  handleUpdate() {
        const state2 =[...this.state.nodes]
        state2[0].name="fruit2";

        this.setState({
          nodes : state2
        })
        console.log("this",this.state.links);
        //FORCE.initForce(this.state.nodes,this.state.links);

}
```